# Jquery fade right to left

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery:

```
jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    width: 'toggle'
  }, speed, easing, callback);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container_content_quick").hide();
  $("#header").click(function() {
    $("#container_content_quick").slideFadeToggle();
    return true;
  });
});
```

Basically fades in #container_content_quick from left to right.

I wonder if its possible to fade right to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element is anchored to the left then the left side will stay in place and the right side will appear to move towards it. If you element is anchored to the right, then the opposite is true. You could achieve this most easily with floats, I would guess.